# Telegram bot Node.js c интерфейсом

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

я делаю бота на NODE.js, хочу сделать интерфейс и отправлять сообщения с сайта.

У меня 3 файла.

1. server.js связь с ботом
2. index.js
3. index.html

Получил данные из input(html), отправляю с помощью Request на server.js.

Как принять эти файлы? Объясните пожалуйста логику(последовательность действий).

я должен создать обработчик, который будет спать, но переодически просыпаться и проверять, если данные пришли? но это бред мне кажется.

Помогите пожалуйста.

index.js

[image: index.js]

index.html

[image: index.html]

server.js

[image: server.js]